# Teamwork problem writing the code with colleagues in bitbucket

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, bitbucket, teamwork-projects

I am writing the code with my team by usin0 the Bitbucket service. The problem is the following:

Since yesterday, when I downloaded the last commit from our public repository I see all projects (folders) but in visual studio where I want to run the application the compiler tells me that some libraries, projects or references are missing. At the same time I see only one of four projects in visual studio(while it must be four). I've tried to rebuild the solution but this does not help.

[image: Folder structure]

[image: Project open in VS]
[image: Error messages]

When I asked one of my colleagues about the problem, he told me that this is a standard procedure and he will give me the access to all libraries and projects when the work will be finished.

My question is: Can I do something to got the access to all missing files?

P.S. I am the owner of Bitbucket repository

Comment: Is it possible that they didn't check in the solution file and/or the project files properly? I don't think its a bitbucket issue but rather improper usage of git console/vsts git management.

Comment: It sounds like your partner doesn't fully understand proper version control procedures as well as he thinks he does. He added new projects, and made calls to that new code, but never "made it part of the solution".  You could manually add that code by choosing "add existing item" from the solution explorer, but that will likely give you merge conflicts once you both try to commit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your colleague their solution build before pushing new changes and all the dependencies / changes to packages.config and project files are pushed in.

Usually a clean and rebuild and a compare between project files will tell you what are the differences.

P.S. if you have a .gitignore file check that too, in case someone added something that is required to your project.